# command-line with variable, doesn't work

Tags: macos, command-line, awk, terminal, zsh

I have a script that uses awk with parameters but I can't find the right syntax to make it functionnal. May be could you help me ?
(under osx, terminal, zsh, command line)

I get a variable who is the path name (it's a awk result)

path_dir="/picture/dir/'

After, I ask this:

```
awk -F"/" '{print $2}' $path_dir
```

But it doesn't work. I get:

```
cant' open file $path_dir
```

My goal is to do this:

```
dir_name=awk -F "/" '{print $2}' $path_dir
```

Then, to use

```
$dir_name
```

But first, awk can't read my `$path_dir`

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Does that directory exist? what does `ls -d /picture/dir` tell you?

Comment: nothing. "/picture/dir" is text, this is the value of $path_dir. This is the search result (with awk) inside a file. I tried to look for inside the text of a file, the name of the created directory to put it in a variable: I want to get as result the text "dir" in my variable $dir_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
dir_name=$(awk -F'/' '{print $2}' <<<$path_dir)
```

this should assign `dir_name` with `picture`

Comment: Is there somewhere to click to accept the answer ? Anyway yes, I accept the answer :-)

Comment: @user2643105 yes. under the number (up/downvote), there is a tick. click to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to:

```
dir_name=`awk -F "/" '{print $2}' $path_dir`
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this:  awk: can't open file /picture/dir/ source line number 1

Comment: @user2643105 it won't work because, awk will take the file `/picture/dir` (even if it is a directory) as input. but what you want is to use literal text "/picture/dir" as input.